# Lenovo SL510 - to external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, lenovo-laptop

I remember someone told me that ny laptop can be used as hard drive and connected to external monitors via some device( forgot the name).  I actually saw it once someone just takes closed lenovo laptop and mounts it on some device without even opening it.  Lenovo apparently has some sort of jack or connectors on the bottom of it.  Can someone suggest what is this so i can look it up please

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a docking station. 
https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-sl-series-laptops/thinkpad-sl510/documents/PD014572?tabName=Accessories

I do not recommend the usb docks, go with the one that the laptop bottom clicks in to.

Comment: Whats the difference between the two? What do i need from hardware for 2 monitors beside the obvious?

Comment: Do i need a spliters or this docking station support dual monitors

Comment: I did some more research on this and the only dock available for your system is https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/migr-76983  It is a USB dock and has 1 DVI output, but it doesnt disable the laptop's monitor port.  So you could have 3 displays active with this.  The monitor attached to the dock, a monitor plugged into the laptop, and the laptop's display.  No splitter needed, and the dock comes with a DVI to VGA adapter in case you need that.